# ComboBox showing file names

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have created a comboBox inside a Windows Form and inside this comboBox I want to show filenames inside a specific directory.

My code Form 1:

```
 private string path = (@"C:\Users\khaab\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ReadingXML\ReadingXML\bin\Debug\Customers");

private void SelectConfigComboBox_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 List<String> Configurations = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path).ToList();
 Path.GetFileName(path);
 SelectConfigComboBox.DataSource = Configurations;
}
```

My problem at this moment is that when I click on the ComboBox it shows me the whole path name I want only the names of the file inside that directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after enumerating all files apply `Path.GetFileName` method to each of them using `Select` extension method:

```
private void SelectConfigComboBox_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   List<String> Configurations = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path)
                                          .Select(p => Path.GetFileName(p))
                                          .ToList();
   SelectConfigComboBox.DataSource = Configurations;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it's not showing anything inside the ComboBox.

Comment: @Khaab, I changed one method `EnumerateDirectories` -> `EnumerateFiles`, because you wrote about "*filenames* inside a specific directory". try with `EnumerateDirectories` again to load all *directories*

Comment: It's working! Great thank you! Is it now possible to load a app.config file inside this file and then load the data of this file inside each specific TextBox?

Comment: @Khaab, with `EnumerateDirectories` you are getting *directory* names, not files. you should specifically search for `app.config` files (another overload with search pattern:`EnumerateDirectories(path, "*.config")`) and read them, using for example method `File.ReadAllText(filename)`

Comment: I don't understand that, is it possible that we can chat through Stackoverflow to discuss that?

Comment: @Khaab, try this: change `path` to folder path where `app.config` is located. then use `EnumerateDirectories(path, "*.config"))`. you should get "app.config". then you can read config with File.ReadAllText: `string text = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(path, "app.config"));`

Answer (score 1):

Get all fileEntries (full path), and then use `Path.GetFileName()` to obtain only the filename of each:

```
List<String> Configurations = new List<string>();
string [] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(path);
foreach(string fileName in fileEntries)
{
  Configurations.Add(Path.GetFileName(fileName);
}
SelectConfigComboBox.DataSource = Configurations;
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it's not showing anything inside the ComboBox.

Answer (score 0):

Before set DataSource use [Path.GetFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) for items in result of Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path).ToList()

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it's not showing anything inside the ComboBox.

Answer (score 0):

`FileInfo` has a `Name` property that only contains the filename part.

```
var files= new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles("*");
var firstFilename = files[0].Name;
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it's not showing anything inside the ComboBox.

Comment: @Khaab you need to assign files to your dropdown.